# Getting ratio of reads to writes on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, statistics

Sorry I am not a DBA so bear with me.  I wanted to get a better understanding of the ratio of reads to writes in our archiecture.  The best to get this is at the database. We are using SQL Server 2008.  Is there anyway to get this without impacting performance and to get smart summaries?  For example, the daily read / write ratio?

Many thanks.

Comment: For physical writes and reads you can use `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats`. For logical reads not sure.

Comment: You could also look at `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` or `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`

Answer (score 4):

This will be incomplete, but it will give you a good idea of the ratios you're looking for. You can use sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to retreive the access from various indexes on the system. If you combine the seeks, scans, and lookups you'll get a good idea of the reads. Something like this:

```
SELECT  ddius.user_updates,
        ddius.user_lookups + ddius.user_scans + ddius.user_seeks AS user_reads
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS ddius
```

This data is cumulative, so you'll need to capture the previous day in order to find the differences between yesterday & today. As I say, this won't give you a perfect measure, but it will move you in the right direction.

Comment: These counters get incremented by 1 when a plan is executed containing (say) the lookup operator irrespective of whether 0 or 1 million lookups happened in reality. [Example here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13752/how-can-dm-db-index-usage-stats-show-0-for-user-seeks-and-user-scans-but-a-large/13756#13756)

Comment: True. Same thing for the writes. But since we're just interested in ratios it's a method. There isn't a pure way to get this done that gives you all of what's needed to establish a perfect solution. That's a big part of why I said it would be incomplete.

Comment: Yes I haven't found a way. `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` has reads and writes but not broken down by DB and only includes cached plans obviously. Couldn't see any performance counters that had this at a DB level either.

Comment: Yeah, it's just not a measure that you can go to one location and get something accurate.